# Azure API Problem When trying to Creat Azure Service Vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create Azure Site Recovery automation but I'm running on a issue with the API.

this is the API I'm Currently using
 `"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{vault_name}?api-version=2023-04-01"`
and this is the body I'm sending to it as a PUT method:

```
backup_storage_config = {
        "location": location,
        "properties": {
            "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
            "redundancySettings": {
            "standardTierStorageRedundancy": "LocallyRedundant",       
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard"
        },
        }
    }
```

But when I do this, the following error shows up: `Exception: HttpResponseError: (InvalidRestApiParameter) redundancySettings parameter is invalid. Please provide a valid redundancySettings`

I'm following this documentation to make the API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/vaults/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#standardtierstorageredundancy

Does anybody now what can be going wrong ?

Read the documentation and tried also using the SDK to make the request but wasn't successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're working with the right API?

I haven't worked with the Azure Recovery Service well enough to know this for sure but it seems like the same configuration can be achieved manually in Azure Portal as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-storage-redundancy

If the configuration discussed in the doc above is the same one that you're trying to create an automation for using ARM deployment, it looks like the Azure Portal is actually using the following API for setting the redundancy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/backup-resource-storage-configs/patch?tabs=HTTP

If the above assumptions are correct, I have tested and was able to change the redundancy values using the [ARM Client tool](https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient) without any issues:
[image]

where the payload in the Body is as follows:

```
{
    "Properties":{
        "StorageModelType":"LocallyRedundant",
        "StorageType":null,
        "StorageTypeState":null,
        "CrossRegionRestoreFlag":false
    }
}
```